# Using checkboxes to retrieve a foreign key, name, and value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm working on a compare system just like verizon wirelesses compare system. I'm retrieving 30 phones from a database and I need to use check boxes to select which phones I want to compare with each other. I have a table that has the name of the phone and the image URL which works fine. My problem is how to retrieve the prodFK, Name, and value like shown below so that I can compare each phone with each other. I really hope that some one is patient enough to help me with this. This is my code to display the phones.

```
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") 
or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = (mysql_num_rows ($data));


//loop for rows
if($numrows >0)
{
    echo "<table width = 100% border = '1' cellspacing = '2' cellpadding = '0'>";

//loop for columns
    $position = 1;
    while ($phones = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        if($position == 1){
            echo "<tr>";}
            echo " <td>"."<img src='".$phones['pictureURL']."' title='".$phones['name']."'/><br /><input type='checkbox' title='".$phones['name']."'/></td> ";
            if($position == 6)
            {
                echo "</tr> "; $position = 1;
            }
            else{
                $position++;
            }
        }

$end = "";
if($position != 1){
for($z=(6-$position); $z>0 ; $z--){
$end .= "<td></td>";
}
$end .= "</tr>";
}

echo $end."</table> ";
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can identify one phone from another by adding properties that specify the db values within the IMG (or INPUT) element, ex.:
<img ProdFK='".$prodFK."  src='".$phones['pictureURL']."' title='".$phones['name']."'/><br /><input type='checkbox' title='".$phones['name']."'/></td> ";

Comment: Well I want to display each attribute that each phone has from the database. Then create a table out of it so that it's similar to any phone comparison website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `input` has no name nor value:

```
<input type='checkbox' title='".$phones['name']."'/>
```

You need to give that a name and a value, then you will know what they selected:

```
"<input type='checkbox' title='".$phones['name']."' name='selection[]' value='".
$phones['id']."'/>"
```

Then, you can access `$_REQUEST['selection']` (which will be an Array) to see which phones they selected:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['selection']) && is_array($_REQUEST['selection'])) {
  $where = array();
  foreach($_REQUEST['selection'] as $id) $where[] = "`id`=".intval($id);
  $where = join(' OR ',$where);
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE $where") or die(mysql_error());
  $numrows = (mysql_num_rows ($data));
  // Display a table of all selected phones' specs
} else {
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") or die(mysql_error());
  $numrows = (mysql_num_rows ($data));
  // Display a selection of all phones to select and compare
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the SQL that I need but not sure how to make it dynamic: select product.id, productAttr.* from product LEFT JOIN productAttr ON product.id=productAttr.prodFK Where product.id=29;

Comment: Use my `WHERE` clause :-) Check my answer, do you see how I built the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Ah ok I see how it's working now. So where you have //Display a table of all selected phone' specs, What should I echo out? I know I need a table tag but not sure which variable to echo out.

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure either... echo out the information you want to display? Your array keys will be the same as the columns of the `productAttr` table. I'd suggest starting with a `var_dump` and going from there.